# Most performant way to copy a Map into an existing Map

Tags: javascript, dictionary, ecmascript-6, clone

I want to overwrite `Map` **b** in the snippet below with the contents of `Map` **a**. I am currently clearing the contents of *b* and then setting the entries one by one. What is a more efficient way (**less garbage**, faster, etc.) of writing the `copyMap` function?

```js
const a = new Map([[1, 2], [2, 10], [3, 20]]);
const b = new Map([[1,5]]);

// I want to copy a into b, at the end b should look like
// b = new Map([[1, 2], [2, 10], [3, 20]]);

console.log(a,b);

function copyMap(srcMap, destMap) {
  destMap.clear();
  
  // Maybe this loop could be done in a single call somehow?
  for(let item of srcMap) {
    destMap.set(item[0], item[1]);
  }
}
copyMap(a, b);

// a and b should have same entries
console.log('a: ',[...a.entries()], 'b: ', [...b.entries()]);
```

Comment: Do you want to mutate `b`, or would you be fine with creating a new `Map`?

Comment: I don't think `copyMap` could get any simpler than what you did. (Maybe use destructuring for `item`, but that's just syntax).

Comment: My main goal is to reduce garbage generation, as it is for a high-performance app where GC pauses can ruin user experience and I want to re-use as much of the already instantiated objects as possible. I do think (from previous experiences) that changing an existing object is faster and generates less garbage than creating a new one.

Comment: I thought maybe there was a faster way of setting all entries from `a` in `b` without iterating over them, something like a bulk copy or like [TypedArray.set()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/set)

Comment: No, `Map`s don't have a bulk copy method. The only method that takes an iterable is the constructor. I don't think it does pre-allocate the memory to the expected size, but you could still try to do `b = new Map(a)`.

Comment: Can you tell us more about your actual use case? What are you doing there, multiple times a second? How large are those maps? Why do you need to copy them at all (or move the values), why can't you just use `a`?

Comment: I have multiple app instances (tens or hundreds) running at 60FPS on a single thread, every several frames a new `a` is received (different for each instance) and I have to save it/copy it into `b`. 
In my specific case, both `a` and `b` have (mostly) the same keys (but different values for those keys), each time the copy function is used, so probably it's better not to clear the map before, but only set/overwrite current keys.

Comment: What does the `Map` represent? Where does `a` come from, you say it is "received"? How is it created and is it used elsewhere? Yes, if they have the same keys then you can avoid the `.clear()` which makes it more probably that no reallocation is happening.

Comment: I save data each few frames, and sometimes I have to go "back in time" and load the data at a specific point, in that case I have to replace the current data with the data at that timestamp, so I have to copy the saved data into the current data.

Comment: So you start by making a copy `a = new Map(b)`, then change `b`, and later load the old values from `a` into `b`? And the `b` map instance is referenced everywhere so that you cannot just overwrite the variable `b = a`, you must mutate `b`?

Comment: Yes, each second I create and save a new copy of `b` in a different list (indexed by time), and also each tick `b` is updated/mutated. But it also happens that sometimes I go back to an element in the list and have to copy that element into `b`, while keeping the original element in the list.

Comment: Ah, I see. I guess then your implementation is really fine, especially if you can avoid clearing the map. An alternative you might want to consider would be immutable maps that allow sharing of older values. It might take less memory overall, but you'll have to evaluate memory pressure.

Answer (score 0):

you can jsut do

```
b=new Map(a)
```

and you need to loose the const declaration for b

Comment: But this way previous b `Map` will become garbage, and I want to avoid creating garbage.

Comment: then why not copy it in a new variable ?

Comment: What do you mean, I just explained above? I do the `copyMap` operation hundreds of times a second, if I create a `new Map` each time it will do a lot of allocations and create a lot of garbage.

Comment: See [Memory Management](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management) to better understand the garbage collection issue that OP is trying to solve here.